# Sharepoint 2007 on Windows 2008

Tags: windows, sharepoint, windows-server-2008

I wanted to get some feedback about the problems we might face if we deploy Sharepoint 2007 on Windows 2008 instead on windows 2003

Answer (score 2):

Windows SharePoint Services 3 is supported just fine on Windows 2008.  You'll need to [make sure that you're using SP1](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2008/01/16/windows-server-2008-and-sharepoint-resources.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

See answers on ServerFault:

- [Installing Office SharePoint 2007 on Windows Server 2008 R2?](https://serverfault.com/questions/63691/installing-office-sharepoint-2007-on-windows-server-2008-r2)
- [Installing Sharepoint 2007 on Windows Server 2008 R2](https://serverfault.com/questions/65949/installing-sharepoint-2007-on-windows-server-2008-r2)

To save you time two main points of the solution are:

1. Create your own slip-streamed installation of SharePoint with the latest Service Pack included (SP3 at the moment) and then install this directly onto Windows Server 2008 R2.
2. Activate .NET Framework 3.5.1 feature in Windows Server to get rid of the [Windows Workflow Foundation error](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5439.this-product-requires-at-least-windows-workflow-foundation-version-3-0-4203-2-error-in-sharepoint-2007-en-us.aspx)